# How to redirect after closing a modal

Tags: javascript

hello How to redirect to a new tab after closing a modal
I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary clear-panier " data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="mymodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Fermer</button>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      window.location.href = "https://retour.be/"
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: What specifically "doesn't work" about it?  Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  Is the event handler invoked at all?  Does `$('#myModal')` find its target element when this code executes?  Please clarify, as well as provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: (Using `mymodal` as ID for the button, and then `myModal` for the modal itself, is really _asking_ to be confused between the two in the future ...)

Comment: Thanks for the help
no no error in the console
Redirection not happening

Answer (score 0):

You may try `window.location.replace()`. This is always working for me. In your example:

```js
window.location.replace("https://retour.be/");
```

**Why isn't your method working?**

Well, window.location.href is a variable, yes. But it doesn't do anything when redefining it, as it's not a function and nothing is listening for a change or similar. That's why the replace() method actually *is* working. It's a function which does exactly what you wanted it to do.

Hope this helps you out :)

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work
Redirection not happening

Comment: You may try the jquery selector without the onReady event of the document

Comment: You can do that as scripts at the end of the body tag are loaded after loading the whole page. That's why it isn't needed to write for the load.

Comment: When you redefine `window.location.href` it do redirect you to the given url